# Small screen C/C++ graphics libraries

Tags: c, user-interface, graphics, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi with a small touch display (320x240) which I want to use as a simple user interface for my robot. For this purpose, I am looking for a basic user interface library for C/C++ which allows me to have a very basic mouse supported UI without using any window manager. Unfortunately, a TUI is not a viable option here, because the display is too small to be used comfortably with such a UI. I also want to stay away from libraries that rely on special hardware support, like OpenGL, for now.

Here comes the question: What libraries could to be suited well for building a very basic mouse supported UI for small screens without using any window manager and which do not rely on special hardware support?

Thanks!

Comment: All GUI libraries I know of happily work without window managers. Just create your window with the right size at (0,0) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/)? It's lightweight graphic lib and should fullfill all your requirements.

Comment: Allegro seems to be basic and lightweight enough. Thank you very much.